# Python Installation: What is file path to python.exe?

Tags: python, installation, filepath

I am trying to schedule my python code (.py) to run in Windows 10 using task scheduler.  In order to do so, I need to indicate where my python.exe file is located.

I downloaded the latest Anaconda to my Windows 10 machine and run my code in jupyter notebook successfully so I should have python.exe somewhere.

I cannot find where the "python.exe" file path is stored in my computer.  Thoughts?

Please see sample example below:

[image]

Comment: It will be located wherever you installed Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get yourself a copy of [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and type `python.exe` into its search box. That will find all Pythons available on your PC.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is it really necessary to get this to find `python.exe`?  I mean this looks like searching through file explorer search bar will do exactly the same.

Comment: @Simon, no, it's not necessary. But it's much faster than Windows. And more reliable, because it does not need Windows Search Indexing.

Comment: @Simon: have you tried the tool? You'll love it. I use it every day.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it quite easily using the `os` module:

First open a Python interpreter, not through terminal but directly (there should be a shortcut on your start menu).

Next get the os module:

```
import os
```

And use the `getcwd()` method to find it:

```
os.getcwd()
```

---

The better way to do it.  If Python is added to path.

Open a command prompt window.  Not the Python interpreter or open Power Shell and type:

```
where python
```

Another way to do it is to type `python.exe` in the file explorer search bar at `C:`.

Comment: How do you execute a Python program if you don't know where your interpreter is?

Comment: @ThomasWeller If you look in the start menu it should be listed there. Then just run the `os.getcwd()` command.  If it is added to path then the commands below will work, if all else fails then searching at `c:` will **definitly** work.

Comment: If there is a shortcut to the Python interpreter, you could look up the properties of that shortcut.